# Git pull/merge one file from another remote repo and merge its code instead of replacing it

Tags: git

I have read many posts and articles about pulling one file in--in a variety of ways--but none of them appear to do merging the way I need.

**Architecture**

I have repo "a" which I develop my app on locally with its remote "a" counterpart. There's also another remote repo "b" which has files I need to stay up-to-date with in my "a" repo; but, I need to keep my own changes too.

**Use Case**

I've committed my local changes to the master branch on my local copy of repo "a". I want to get the latest code from "components/config.js" on the master branch of remote repo "b", and have it merge with my changes to the file on my local repo "a" in the same equivalent directory ("components/config.js") on my master branch.

**Failed attempts to merge the files**

I can't do `git pull --allow-unrelated-histories remote-b master` because it will cause conflicts in other files (or add/remove files) and I only want to be concerned with the file in point.

I could do `git fetch remote-b` and then `git checkout FETCH_HEAD -- components/config.js` but that simply replaces the file contents instead of merging.

**Problem**

I still can't merge (not replace), the code for only one specified file from another remote repo, into the local file equivalent in another repo.

Answer (score 0):

To merge a file you need 3 different copies of the file — base version, changed version and the current version to merge to. You only talk about 2 copies — in repo "a" and "b".

You have to decide what is the base version. It is an old commit in repo "b", let's say it's commit "b-old". Now you do diff between the base and the changed copies and save the diff:

```
cd repo-b
git diff b-old:components/config.js components/config.js > ../config.js.patch
```

Then you move the patch to the repo "a" and apply the diff to the current version:

```
cd repo-a
git apply ../config.js.patch
```

Resolve merge conflicts and commit.

Comment: Aside from the (possibly needed) complexity, that is an approach. While testing this, I found that the file I experimented with was so different that Git can't successfully apply the patch--even with a variety of flags to help.  I'm still hoping there is a file-to-file command to merge, just like the repo-to-repo mentioned above merges all files as expected: `git pull --allow-unrelated-histories remote-b master`.